# Changing cursor style on pointermove for specified layer

Tags: javascript, canvas, openlayers, openlayers-3

quick (and I believe for some of you an easy) question regarding cursor styling while hovering above geojson layer/s.

So, I have one clip layer that I'm using to create a mask around wms layers, and another one that represents some administrative areas.
As you can see in picture below
[image]

What I would like is to change style of cursor when I'm hovering above administrative areas but it seems that I'm missing something.

I'm trying to isolate to layer only administrative borders layer using this block of code:

```
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
if (e.dragging) return;
var pixel = e.map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
var hit = e.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    return vectorJLS.get('layer_name') === 'jls';
});
   e.map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

**UPDATE**

While JGH tweak code a bit it still doesn't work. I've detected that problem lies in layer that I'm using for mask clipping, when removed, code that JGH provided, works.

Here is code that I'm using for mask clipping

```
 var clipLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
     source: new ol.source.ImageVector({
         source: new ol.source.Vector({
             url: 'geojson/clip_wgs.geojson',
             format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
         }),
         style: new ol.style.Style({
             fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                 color: 'black'
             })
         })
     })
 });


clipLayer.on('postcompose', function(e) {
    e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
});
clipLayer.on('precompose', function(e) {
    e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
});
clipLayer.setMap(map);
```

Is it possible to somehow ignore clip layer when changing cursor style or should I take another approach?

**UPDATE - 2**

I've tweaked code a bit, but still without any success while clipedLayer is on.

```
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
    if (e.dragging) return;

    var pixel = e.map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
    // initialize the hit variable to false (not found)

    var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, {
        layerFilter: function(layer) {
            return vectorJLS.get('layer_name') === 'jls';
        }
    });

    console.log(hit)
});
```

Interesting problem if I might add

Comment: as written, it is dependent on the layer order. You would need to exit your function once it as found the layer of interest

Comment: @JGH could you please elaborate a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, with help from fellow JGH I've found appropriate solution for my problem. 
Searching release pages and google machine I've stumbled upon some interesting information regarding layer filters and its usage in method **hasFeatureAtPixel**. This block of code is valid for versions below **3.20.1** but more about that on [OpenLayers Git](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases?after=v3.20.1)

```
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
    if (e.dragging) return;
    var pixel = e.map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
    var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, {
        layerFilter: function(layer) {
            return layer.get('layer_name') === 'jls';
        }
    });
     e.map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

For newer versions you should use layer filter like this (I'm using 4.6.5)

```
map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel, {
  layerFilter: layerFilterFn.bind(layerFilterThis)
});
```

Or for my particular problem like this

```
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
    if (e.dragging) return;
    var pixel = e.map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
    var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, {
        layerFilter: function(layer) {
            return layer.get('layer_name') === 'jls';
        }
    });
     e.map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

In your function, you are basically looping through all the layers at the mouse location. In that loop, if the layer has the proper name you set the pointer, else if it has a different name, you remove the pointer (or set it to something else).

As it is, it is dependent on the layer order:
ex: layer 1 = target -> set custom pointer.  Layer 2 = other layer -> remove pointer. ==> final pointer: removed

ex:  Layer 1 = other layer -> remove pointer. Layer 2 = target -> set custom pointer. ==> final pointer: custom pointer

The looping occurs when you set the `hit` variable, i.e. it corresponds to the last layer only as you are overriding the value for each layer.

```
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
  if (e.dragging) return;

  var pixel = e.map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
  // initialize the hit variable to false (not found)
  var hit = false;
  e.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    if ( vectorJLS.get('layer_name') === 'jls') {
          //IF we have found the layer, flag it (but don't return anything!)
          hit = true;
     }
  });

  e.map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort but unfortunately code above doesn't work while clip layer is activated. I ll explain further in updated question...